# Segue data transfer and data access

Tags: xcode, segue, data-transfer

Helo!

I feel really silly asking for help, but oh well I got stuck with my first Xcode project.

So I am creating a calculator and I have created a method that prints out two results to two STrings

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {


(...)


stringResult=[[NSString alloc]
                            initWithFormat:@"%1.2d",intResult];
stringTimeResult=[[NSString alloc]
                        initWithFormat:@"%1.2d",intTimeResult];


[stringTimeResult release];
[stringResult release];

 }
```

And I have prepared Segue transfer two Strings to Two Labels on a new view, creating a form or result to a given calculations.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Answer"])
{
[segue.destinationViewController setTransferStr:stringTimeResult];
[segue.destinationViewController setTransferStr2:stringResult];
}
```

And a view did load in new controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.TimeResult.text = self.transferStr;
self.Result.text = self.transferStr2;
}
```

However, im experiencing a lot of trouble! Forgive me my lack of knowledge but i just can't figure it out!

The main bit is that the answer of the calculation is displayed on two labels on a next view controller!

Thank you for your help in advance

Grace

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to solve this problem? I have no clue but it does not transfer the data. Is the Time result kept within the calculate method, do i have to return it in a way? Is anything wrong with my segue implementation?

Comment: please make your question a bit more understandable, you just giving facts.

Comment: Im so sorry! Basically this whole procedure does not update the two labels at the end. It keeps them blank. The first method is in the same view as the segue method. How can I tacle this? What am I doing wrong? Why is it keeping blank on the label?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 view controllers "vcA" and "vcB", connected by segue called"AtoBSegue"
now you have some data want to transfer from vcA -> AtoBSegue -> vcB:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AtoBSegue"]){
        vcB *viewcontrollerB = (vcB*)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewcontrollerB.labelAtvcB = self.labelAtvcA.text; //labelAtvcB is the label from vcB, labelAtvcA is the label from vcA.
    }
}
```

Note: please define the exact name as you use labelAtvcB in vcB (destination view controller)

Comment: Thank you! However, changing the details to yours allowed me to tackle the few problems i did not mention, but still the ui labels remain empty. Is it because the function calculate is in the first view controller with the segue method? Is it because the calculate method is void and you can not reach the calculation result? I am clueless.